# php foreach not working as expected in one situation

Tags: php, foreach

I like foreach. I've used it many times, successfully. While I don't necessarily understand the exact specifics of how or why it works, it has, until now, never stopped me from using it with the desired result. So here is my scenario...

I have a bit of php on the backend of a form that allows users to upload certain types of files to be saved into a MySQL database. I know some of you will say saving a file inside a DB is not good, but lets just put that aside for now as there is very much a 50/50 split opinion on this and no real valid reason why it is bad, at all. The upload functionality works perfectly. I want the a display table to appear of the list of relevant files the user has placed into the DB. Here the weird foreach trouble starts. This is my code:

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $database.appFiles WHERE appID = :appid AND uaID = :uaid AND applicationKey = :applicationkey");
    $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uaid', $uaID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->bindParam(':applicationkey', $applicationKey, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
    $stmt->execute();
    $fRes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
if(count($fRes > "0")) {
    //var_dump($fRes);
    foreach ($fRes as $value) {
        echo "  </tr>\n";
        echo "  <tr style=\"background: ".cycleColours()." border-bottom: 1px dotted #c0c0c0;\">\n";
        echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".$fRes[0][fileName]."</td>\n";
        echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".$fRes[0][fileMime]."</td>\n";
        echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".$fRes[0][fileSize]."</td>\n";
        echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".uts2date($fRes[0][dateUploaded])."</td>\n";
        echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">Del</td>\n";
    }

} else {
    echo "  </tr>\n";
    echo "  <tr style=\"border-bottom: 1px dotted #c0c0c0;\">\n";
    echo "   <td class=\"center\" style=\"padding: 5px;\" colspan=\"5\"><i>No files have been uploaded for this application yet</i></td>\n";
}
```

And when I have zero results in the DB I don't get any output (my "else" is not working), when I have one file uploaded I successfully get the output for that file as expected. When I have two files uploaded I get two rows each echoing out the details of the first file - repetition. No mention of the second file appears. This pattern goes on for the more files I have uploaded successfully. If 20 files have been uploaded, I get 20 rows all nice and tidy, telling me the same info about the first file uploaded, 20 times in a row.

I have tried modifying my

```
    foreach ($fRes as $value) {
```

syntax and used:

```
    foreach ($fRes as $value => $key) {
```

But I get the same result. Seems to make no difference at all. The data extracted from the DB is an array (you can see my commented out var_dump($fRes); that I used to check it). Interestingly when I change the $fRes[0][fileName] to $fRes[1][fileName] I get the name of the second file, etc. This would seem to show that for some reason each file is in a parallel separate array? Why? And how do I make this work correctly as expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to change `$fRes[0]` to `$value`.  If you use `$fRes[0]` you will always get the first record with each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you, correct and saved me from implementing a i++ counter to replace my [0]. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you are inside foreach loop

```
 foreach ($fRes as $value)
```

you get your loop data from $value

Answer (score 0):

you have little mistake here and there.To be clear `count($fRes > "0")` dont know how its working to get you to `if condition` it should be like this `count($fRes) > 0` or `!empty($fRes)`.

```
// its not count($fRes > "0")
// $fRes[0] is getting the first result array so change it to $value
if(count($fRes)  > 0) {
//var_dump($fRes);
foreach ($fRes as $value) {
    echo "  </tr>\n";
    echo "  <tr style=\"background: ".cycleColours()." border-bottom: 1px dotted #c0c0c0;\">\n";
    echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".$value['fileName']."</td>\n";
    echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".$value['fileMime']."</td>\n";
    echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".$value['fileSize']."</td>\n";
    echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">".uts2date($value['dateUploaded'])."</td>\n";
    echo "   <td style=\"padding: 5px;\">Del</td>\n";
}

}
```